# Minecraft Forge Mod: gradle task failed, "Could not resolve dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-42.0.1:userdev"

Tags: java, windows, powershell, gradle, minecraft-forge

when I run "./gradlew build", I get the error message:
`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'flashnpcs'.

> Could not resolve dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-42.0.1:userdev

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`

I am using Visual Studio Code

I have tried changing a bunch of code in build.gradle, but nothing seems to be working. I was hoping I would have my project done by now, but there is one error that I can't seem to fix.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url = 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net' }
        maven { url = 'https://repo.spongepowered.org/repository/maven-public/' }
        maven { url = 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url = 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', name: 'ForgeGradle', version: '5.1+', changing: true
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.github.johnrengelman:shadow:7.1.1'
        classpath 'org.spongepowered:mixingradle:0.7-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'org.spongepowered.mixin'

group = 'flash'
version = '1.2.0'
archivesBaseName = 'flashnpcs'

java.toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)

minecraft {
    mappings channel: 'official', version: "1.19.2"

    accessTransformer = file('src/main/resources/META-INF/accesstransformer.cfg')

    runs {
        client {
            workingDirectory project.file('run/client')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            arg "-mixin.config=flashnpcs.mixins.json"

            mods {
                flashnpcs {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }

        server {
            workingDirectory project.file('run/server')

            property 'forge.logging.markers', 'REGISTRIES'

            property 'forge.logging.console.level', 'debug'

            arg "-mixin.config=flashnpcs.mixins.json"

            mods {
                flashnpcs {
                    source sourceSets.main
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

mixin {
    config "flashnpcs.mixins.json"
    add sourceSets.main, "flashnpcs.refmap.json"

    showMessageTypes = true
}

sourceSets.main.resources { srcDir 'src/generated/resources' }

dependencies {
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-42.0.1'



    annotationProcessor 'org.spongepowered:mixin:0.8.5:processor'

//    FOR SOME REASON THIS DOESN'T LOAD DURING RUNTIME -,-
//    implementation 'org.json:json:20211205'
//    shadow 'org.json:json:20211205'
}

/*shadowJar {
    archiveBaseName.set('flashnpcs-shadow')
    archiveClassifier.set('')
    archiveVersion.set(project.version)

    minimize()

    dependencies {
//        include(dependency('org.json:json:20211205'))
    }
}*/

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes([
                "Specification-Title"     : "flashnpcs",
                "Specification-Vendor"    : "FlashHUN",
                "Specification-Version"   : "1",
                "Implementation-Title"    : project.name,
                "Implementation-Version"  : project.version,
                "Implementation-Vendor"   : "FlashHUN",
                "MixinConfigs"            : "flashnpcs.mixins.json",
                "Implementation-Timestamp": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        ])
    }
}

repositories {

}

//jar.dependsOn shadowJar
//jar.enabled = false    Why was this here again?

jar.finalizedBy('reobfJar')
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That dependency looks odd, usually dependencies are in the form company:software:version, and depending on whether I look at your title or your build script, you have a trailing `-42.0.1` or `-42.0.1:userdev`.

Try to remove that, i.e., use

```
dependencies {
    minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2'
}
```

See [the maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.1.25).

Comment: It still doesn't work, it just says `Could not resolve dependency: net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2:userdev`

Comment: @Creeper39x Dude, I told you to remove the "-42.0.1:userdev" part, and you show me an error that still has it?! I copied your build script in a new project and after making the change I suggested in my answer, it resolved all dependencies correctly.

Comment: there's no `userdev` part though... I removed the `42.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your versions mixed up. Forge doesn't have a `1.19.2` version called `42.0.1`. There is a [42.0.1](https://maven.minecraftforge.net/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.1-42.0.1/forge-1.19.1-42.0.1-changelog.txt) version for `1.19.1`.

I'm not sure why you're building against early versions of 1.19. I would recommend using `1.19.4`:

```
minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.4-45.1.2'
```

However, if you wanted 1.19.2, it would be:

```
minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.2-43.2.14'
```

If you specifically needed `42.0.1`, it would need to be 1.19.1:

```
minecraft 'net.minecraftforge:forge:1.19.1-42.0.1'
```

I would recommend picking a version, then downloading the `Mdk` (Mod Development Kit) from [Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/) and then either modifying or referring back to their build script.

Comment: I tried that, but I just get the error https://pastebin.com/f0rWcVzE. How do I solve this?

Comment: If you're trying to use `runClient`, ensure you've first run the `gen<Ide>Runs` task. If you're trying to `build` and still getting that error, do as I said and download the Mdk and use theirs. If that works, try to find what you've done wrong by comparing them. If it doesn't, you may have a network/firewall issue.